# How to redirect Contact form to index page?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, indexing, contacts

```
  <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


$email_to = "raju@saciwaters.org";

$email_subject = "Your email subject line";

function died($error) {

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

}

if(!isset($_POST['full_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['subject']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['message'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

}


$full_name = $_POST['full_name']; // required

$subject = $_POST['subject']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$message = $_POST['message']; // required

$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';



 if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }


$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";



 if(!preg_match($string_exp,$full_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$subject)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($message) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($full_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>
<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: please format your question, and add more explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *header()* function:

```
header("Location: urlToWhichYouWantToRedirect")
```